# Physics fixed time step with client/server games

Tags: 2d, physics-engine, timestep

I'm trying to make a 2D platforming multiplayer game with client/server system.
I want to use Node.js and Phaser for the display.

I read a lot about fixedTimeStep : http://gafferongames.com/game-physics/fix-your-timestep/

Do you think it's viable with JS (and Phaser)?
Do you think it's possible to decouple update() and render() loop with a single-threaded language like JS?

Comment: Yeah, I think it is possible.  Next question?